# Security of files in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, security, encryption

I am creating a simple cloud based **storage system** with **jsp** as back end.I used RSA encryption/decryption for storing files on server,then i also ensured security of private/public keys.But how the **security of source program files** can be ensured because if they are accessed then whole procedure of encryption decryption would be known?Is there any way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle

Comment: Relying on the security of your source code as a safety mechanism is also known as "security through obscurity".